# Edit file in Network Shared Folder without domain

Tags: c#, networking, permissions, shared-directory, networkcredentials

Server pc has a shared folder Which has everyone read permision. But server is not in a domain. I know, local user credentials, and they are in administrators group. But I can't edit this files from winform with c#.

How can I edit files from client. I don't want to use WCF Service because of filesize.

I tried impersonation class but it is working in domain. But I don't have domain.

What should I do?

Comment: You should use the name of the server as domain. Every user is in a "domain"

Comment: I tried this before, but not worked.